# htaccess rules filtered on IP

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following htaccess rule I'd like to apply for every IP address apart from mine. I basically want to show a "site is down" page for everyone apart from myself. How is this best achieved?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/indexTEMP.php$ 
RewriteRule $ /indexTEMP.php [R=307,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache variable is `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Untested but should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/indexTEMP.php$ 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.0\.1$ 
RewriteRule $ /indexTEMP.php [R=307,L]
```

this applies the rule to every IP except 192.168.0.1.